# Summary (avg, min, max) of multiple fields - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports in Visual Studio

I would like to be able to display total minimum, maximum and/or average across several multiple fields.

My scenario: 
In one measuremet, several probes are measured. There are multiple measurements of the same.

In dataset (let's call it Measurement) are fields called K1, K2, ..., K10 (probes 1 to 10). I display average of series (multiple measurements) for K1's, K2's,...
But is it possible to make formula or field, where I could have total average from all rows (all probes in all measurements) from K1 - K10?

Answer (score 0):

If all probes K1  to K10 have the same weight in your measurement, then 
Average(Avegerage (Ki at row j) over the rows) = Average (Ki,j), right ?

Therefore create a formula
Average per row = (K1 + K2 +... +K10)/10

and then insert a summary field as an average of "Average per row"

Considering the Min and Max, there's no weight involved, so the formula will be
Minimum per row = Min(MakeArray({K1},{K2},...)
Maximum per row = Max(MakeArray({K1},{K2},...)
and then inserting the summary accordingly